# How are CouchDB Document ID's Calculated?

Tags: hash, couchdb

How are the CouchDB Document ID's calculated?

BA1F48C5418E4E68E5183D5BD1F06476

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code?

Comment: Check the source: http://github.com/halorgium/couchdb/blob/master/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl

Comment: good idea, never thought of that, though that's all I do for ruby and actionscript :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are type4 UUIDs. Basically just a random string that conforms to the type4 standard of uuids.